# Wrong position google tracking

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

hi sorry for my english I'll do my best to explain my problem

I'm making a web application and I'm using google map api to track my position 
but the problem is that the position is not exact , its not wrong but its near of me and every browser gives an other position also near of me .

besides my iphone gives the exact position when i use the application of tracking (iphone Maps),
so i tried to open my application on my iphone with safari but its the same problem.

this is the code :

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
            var lng=position.coords.longitude;
            var lat=position.coords.latitude;
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),{
                zoom: 19,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
            });
},geo_error,geo_options);

function geo_error() {
        alert("Sorry, no position available.");
    }

var geo_options = {
      enableHighAccuracy: true, 
      maximumAge        : 3000, 
      timeout           : 27000
};
```

Comment: Do you try it on other device? Do you have some personal data on this phone?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the iPhone application gives the exact position? I believe it can be normal that the given position is approximate because it's calculated through the nearest mesh. Maybe some of your personal data detained by Apple corrupt the accuracy of the position.

Try to test it on another device.